# The method getImage isn't defined

Tags: flutter, dart, imagepicker

I am using [image_picker 0.6.7+17](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) library in order to take an image using the phone camera.
I am using an android device and not an ios device.

### A problem

It seems like that `getImage` method is not defined, I took this exact code from the [docs](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker):

```
  final picker = ImagePicker();

  Future getImage() async {
    final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
  }
```

I am getting this error:

```
lib/pickers/image_picker.dart:17:37: Error: The method 'getImage' isn't defined for the class 
'ImagePicker'.
 - 'ImagePicker' is from 'package:chat_app/pickers/image_picker.dart' 
('lib/pickers/image_picker.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'getImage'.
final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
                                ^^^^^^^^
```

---

**What I have done so far:**

- Added the dependency to my pubspec.yaml: file

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
  cloud_firestore: 0.13.5
  firebase_auth: 0.16.1
  image_picker: ^0.6.7+17
```

- Added `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` to the `AndroidManifest.xml` file
- Also Imported `import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart'` to use this library

---

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure the `ImagePicker` you are using is not the one from this `package:chat_app/pickers/image_picker.dart` ? Maybe there is a class name conflict and you must rename your own `ImagePicker` class

Answer (score 7):

You are trying to use an old API with a plugin version that specifies to use the new API.
Old API

```
File image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(...)
```

New API

```
final _picker = ImagePicker();
.
.
.
PickedFile image = await _picker.getImage(...)
```

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem I solved by defining the picker like that

```
 final picker = ImagePicker();
```

and then use this

```
    Future<void> _chooseImage() async {
  var pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just upgrade to latest version of image_picker.
And replace getImage by pickImage bcz getImage has deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

1)you may forget import the library of "image picker":import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

2)or import wrong library with the same name with some differences in the syntax of Sentence